# how to replace repeated phrases with just one

Tags: r, regex

I have the following string

`PC Model 123, PC Model 456, PC Model XYZ, PC Model A156`

I would like to collapse the string into

`PC Model 123/456/XYZ/A156`

How do I use regex to perform the string operation?

I can identify the repeated phrase "PC Model", but I can't remove the redundant one and just keep the first one.

Comment: How about removing all "PC Model" first, then concatenate the result to "PC Model" string?

Comment: ha, I was thinking the same, was thinking if there's a regex pattern I could do a search and replace in one line.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Does the following work for you (in Python)?

```
str1 = "PC Model 123, PC Model 456, PC Model XYZ, PC Model A156"
str2 = re.sub(r', PC Model\s+', r'/', str1)
```

Output

```
 PC Model 123/456/XYZ/A156
```

[Edit]
I can think of a way but requires to rerun the expression multiple times.

```
str1 = "NB Model 555, PC Model 123, PC Model 456, PC Model XYZ, PC Model A156, PC Model 999, NEW Model FOO"
str2 = re.sub(r'(\S+ Model) (\S+),\s+\1 (\S+)', r'\1 \2/\3', str1)
str2 = re.sub(r'(\S+ Model) (\S+),\s+\1 (\S+)', r'\1 \2/\3', str2)
```

Output:

```
B Model 555, PC Model 123/456/XYZ/A156, PC Model 999, NEW Model FOO
```

It combines the models pairwise, so you need to run the expression a few times. Notice that the same model needs to be consecutive

Comment: ok this works in R as well, but if I have string like

"NB Model 123, PC Model 456, PC Model XYZ" 

then the code above will return

NB Model 123, 456/XYZ" which is not what I want.

Comment: that's works well! what does \S+ really do?

I noticed that if I have 

PC Model 123, PC Model 456, PC Model XT ABC, 

the code above will only return

PC Model 123/456, PC Model XT ABC